# How to copy only new files using "scp" command?

Tags: scp

I was copying hundreds of files to another computer using the `scp` command that I got the `stalled` [error](https://askubuntu.com/q/82984/56410). Now I am going to copy the files again. Is there any way to avoid copying the already copied files?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `rsync` for it. `rsync` is really designed for this type of operation.

Syntax:

```
rsync -avh /source/path/ host:/destination/path
```

or

```
rsync -a --ignore-existing /local/directory/ host:/remote/directory/
```

When you run it first time it will copy all content then it will copy only new files.

If you need to tunnel the traffic through a SSH connection (for example, for confidentiality purposes), as indicated by you originally asking for a SCP-based solution, simply add `-e ssh` to the parameters to `rsync`. For example:

```
rsync -avh -e ssh /source/path/ host:/destination/path
```

Comment: Is `--ignore-existing` really required?

Comment: Because in this example of manual: `rsync -t *.c foo:src/` -> "This  would  transfer  all  files  matching  the pattern *.c from the current directory to the directory src on the machine foo. **If any of the files already exist on the remote system then the rsync remote-update protocol is used to update the file by sending only the differences**"

Comment: I typically use `rsync -avuzh /source/path/ host:/destination/path`. That does the whole job in one command, and on subsequent invocations, only transfers the files that need it.

Comment: I don't get why the first one (`-avh`)  would do the requested thing. (the second one I get)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to stick with scp for any reason, you might remove **w** permissions on your local data (if you have the right to do it) and scp won't touch it. To be more precise:

1. `chmod a-w  local/*.tar.gz` (in your local dir)
2. `scp remote/*.tar.gz local`

This is not very efficient, nice but might help if you need a fast temporary  solution without changing to something else than scp. (Kudos: [scp without replacing existing files in the destination](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination) )

Answer (score 9):

There was no exact answer on how to do this with SCP, since that was what the original question was asking.

`sudo find /files/ -type f -exec chmod a-w {} \;`

`scp -r username@server.com:/file/location/* /files`

When it's done copying the files change the permissions back:

`sudo chmod a+w -R /files`