# How do I merge identically named files?

Tags: files, rsync, scp, merge

My question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination) but the answers don't address how I would like to solve it in my case:

Background:
I have two computers generating experimental results that are filed in directories based on timestamps.  E.g.:

```
190525184212  190525184433  190525185428  190525194813 ...
```

I am moving the results to one host computer using `rsync` (with `--remove-source-files`) but since it is possible for two experiments to start during the same second it is possible that this will overwrite results already on the host computer.

What I would like is it append to the directory names when they are identical.  Something like this:

```
190525184212  190525184433  190525184433_1  190525185428  190525194813 ...
```

(The alternative would be for each machine to add its own unique id to the directory names to avoid conflicts but that means hashing the hostname or something and I am not expecting many conflicts so the solution above would be more appealing to me)

I'm guessing I have to write some kind of bash script (like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330426/how-to-copy-merge-two-directories-and-if-two-files-have-the-same-name-rename-the) but it was down-voted)?  But was hoping for a ready-made solution.

thanks.

Footnote: The sub-directories are not all in one main directory as implied above.  There are more than one sub-directory so solutions have to be recursive.

Comment: Not getting any feedback, I'll assume this is not a good idea and do the merge operation in Python.

Comment: the title of your post is convoluted ... a simpler title may attract more attention .... something like `how do I merge identically named files?`

Comment: @jsotola They don't want to merge the files though, they want to rename them if they already exist.

Comment: rsync with "no clobber" sounds (to me) like one should use "cp" with appropriate command options, something like:  cp --backup=existing -t <src> <dest>

Comment: The new title is misleading.  Maybe "How do I merge two sets of files without over-writing duplicates?" would be better.

Comment: @Bill That sounds better to me. You should edit your question with the new title.

Comment: @Theophrastus I'm not sure that `cp` works here, since it has to be recursive.

Comment: @Sparhawk, you are missing the point of my comment ... the title does not have to, and usually cannot, describe everything in detail .... however, a cryptic title may keep some people from actually reading the post

Comment: @jsotola Agreed, but here I think the new title directly conflicts with the question. They do not want to merge the files at all, but do the opposite, i.e. keep them separate.

Comment: A (shell) scripted solution would usually mean you have no password prompt for login - or be very insecure in storing you PW as string.

Comment: If you are looking to distinguish 'same name' from 'same file' then why not just script a `find`, compare file names and rename any files with the same names but different `MD5` or `SHA256` hashes?

Comment: most simple solution for your problem (not your question) would be to append hostnames to output file names in the prog which generates them and later merge them…